# Value of an html input text sent to a .Net MVC controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I try to send an html input text value to a controller. I can't use a form post because my modal dialog is already in a form.

Here's the code :

```
@foreach (var annonce in Model.AnnoncesRecherchees)
            {
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="@("AjouterVisiteVirtuelleModal" + @annonce.Reference)" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Ajouter visite virtuelle annonce @annonce.Reference</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-floating">
                                <input id="visitevirtuelle" class="form-control" autocomplete="" aria-required="false" />
                                <label class="form-label"></label>
                                <span asp-validation-for="Ville" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>*@
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Acheteur" asp-action="AjouterVisiteVirtuelle" asp-route-annonceId="@annonce.ID" asp-route-visiteVirtuelle="document.getElementById("visitevirtuelle").value">Ajouter une visite virtuelle</a>
                        
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  
                </div>
```

I want the parameter "asp-route-visiteVirtuelle" to have the value of the input text "visite virtuelle".

But it doesn't work

PLease help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag helper in anchor link render the url in `href` when the page load, so you cannot use js to add the value to `asp-route-visiteVirtuelle`.

Here is a whole working demo:

```
@foreach (var annonce in Model.AnnoncesRecherchees)
{
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#@("AjouterVisiteVirtuelleModal" + @annonce.Reference)">
  Launch demo modal
</button>    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="@("AjouterVisiteVirtuelleModal" + @annonce.Reference)" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">                      
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Ajouter visite virtuelle annonce @annonce.Reference</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-floating">
                               //add event here......................
                        <input onchange="ChangeUrl(this)" id="visitevirtuelle" class="form-control" autocomplete="" aria-required="false" />
                        <label class="form-label"></label>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Ville" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Acheteur" asp-action="AjouterVisiteVirtuelle" asp-route-annonceId="@annonce.ID" >Ajouter une visite virtuelle</a>                           
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>                      
    </div>
}
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function ChangeUrl(event)
        {
            var visiteVirtuelleVal = $(event).val();
            var anchor = $(event).closest('.modal-body').siblings('.modal-footer').find('a').attr('href');
            $(event).closest('.modal-body').siblings('.modal-footer').find('a').attr('href',anchor+"&visiteVirtuelle="+visiteVirtuelleVal);
        }
    </script>
}
```